# Fourier transform of $f(t)=P_{ro}(1-\frac{t}{t_0})$ if t$<t_0$ and $0$ elsewhere

Tags: fourier-analysis, physics, fourier-series, fourier-transform

Is this right? and how do I draw the Fourier transform graph

\begin{align*}
   F(\omega) & = \int_{0}^{t_0}P_{ro}\Bigl(1-\frac{t}{t_0}\Bigr)\exp{(-jwt)}\,dt\\
          & = P_{ro}\Bigl(1-\frac{t}{t_0}\Bigr)\frac{\exp{(-jwt)}}{-jw}
+\int_{0}^{t_0}\frac{\exp{(-jwt)}}{-jw}\frac{P_{ro}}{t_0}\,dt\\
F(\omega) & = P_{ro}\Bigl(1-\frac{t}{t_0}\Bigr)\frac{\exp{(-jwt)}}{-jw} +\frac{P_{ro}}{t_0}\frac{\exp{(-jwt)}}{(-jw)^2}
\end{align*}
Applying the limits $0$ $<$ t $<$ $t_o$

\begin{align*}
F(\omega) & = P_{ro}(1 + \frac{\exp{(-jwt)}}{(-jw)^2} -\frac{1}{t_0})
\end{align*}

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE, can you please explain what is $Pro$ exactly? also it would be better if you can change $t0$ to $t_0$ using t_0 in math environment

Comment: Thanks. $Pro$ is a pressure.